# An issue of getting an Adwords MCC

Tags: c#, .net, google-ads-api

I saw a post from google "AdWords API v201509 sunset reminder" which the version v201509 was deprecated in on February 2, 2016.

[AdWords API v201509 sunset reminder](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.co.il/2016/05/adwords-api-v201509-sunset-reminder.html)

I built a function which check if my Adwords MCC is valid :

```
public string IsAdwordsMCCValid(string mcc)
    {
        bool isAuthenticated = CheckAdwordsAuthentication();
        if (!isAuthenticated)
        {
            return AdwordsErrors.OAuthNull.ToString();
        }
        AdWordsUser tempUser = adWordsUser;
        (tempUser.Config as AdWordsAppConfig).ClientCustomerId = mcc;
        CampaignService campaignService=(CampaignService)tempUser.GetService(AdWordsService.v201509.CampaignService);

        Selector selector = new Selector();
        selector.fields = new string[] {
    "Id", "Name"
  };

        try
        {
            campaignService.get(selector); **
            ModifyMCC(mcc.Trim());
            return "success";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        return "not valid";
    }
```

When i reach  the line with the ** i get an exception  : "The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found."

Is there anything i need to change in this line of code ? :

```
 CampaignService campaignService=(CampaignService)tempUser.GetService(AdWordsService.v201509.CampaignService);
```

Thanks in advance!